# Выключаеться компьютер без причины в любое время

Tags: ноутбук

Всем привет, уже сколько времени меня мучает проблема, что компьютер(вообще это ноутбук, но используеться как десктоп) выключаеться без причины или выдает синий экран смерти. Я уже несколько раз переустанавливал винду, поставил вот 11 первый раз, думал мб пофикситься, но нет.
Это не зависит от игры или открого софта, я могу играть в какую-то игру он выключится, я могу смотреть видео/сериал он выключиться. Я ставлю ноут с видео на ночь каждый раз и в 99% случаев когда я просыпаюсь, он включен и экран логина, хотя я ставлю таймер на 3 часа(то есть, он выключаеться не из-за таймера).

Ноутбук Lenovo Legion 5 15arh05 (4800h, 1650ti, 16gb, 11Win64x). Биос последний, драйвера обновляются автоматически виндой, должны быть последней версии. Ноут чистый, не грееться.

Эта проблема встречаеться и у других владельцев такого же ноутбука, решения причины я не нашел, а нести в сервисный центр нету времени, тем более если нести по гарантии, займет очень много времени.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://pastebin.com/Uma2qNxC - 1 строчка Ошибки(ее описание).
https://pastebin.com/Bm50DycC - 2 строчка Сведения(ее описание).

На 11 винде я не успел еще застать выключение или синий экран, но из прошлого опыта были постоянные ошибки irql_not_less_or_equal, SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED, DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION(это всего 1 или 2 раза была). Я гуглил решения этих проблем, но нечего не получалось.

Если надо какие-то другие данные о ошибках, какие-то  логи и тд без проблем скину. Помогите, пожалуйста)

P.S Есть подозрение, что ***** Леново использует кривые драйвера, которые надо переустановить на нормальные, но я хз как выследить те самые кривые драйвера. У меня еще сама устанавливаеться время от времени fn hotkey utility lenovo, сама. Хотя другого софта от леново у меня нету(Vantage, Service Bridge и тд у меня нету), так что может быть еще проблема в биосе.

Comment: как-то не густо у вас в EventLog'e...

Comment: а вы уверены что у вас с железом все в порядке?.. очень может быть что у вас проц или видеочип перегреваются и он отрубается при нагреве. ибо это не синий экран...винда сама посылает запрос на выключение системы...

Comment: если вы не хотите нести ноут в сервис просто `чтобы чтобы` - поставьте какой-нить софт который отслеживает и журналирует температуру на чипах, плате - и при следующем случае - посмотрите на показания...если вырубается при достижении каких-то цифр определенных  - то несите в сервис и чините железки

Comment: Не густо потому что поставил фильтр на какие-то 3 ошибки, которые были в интернете.

Я уверен что железо не перегреваеться, потому что я только что, буквально, читал ваши сообщения и он просто моментально выключился и начал запускать винду. Хотя на заднем плане нечего кроме браузера не работало.

https://imgur.com/a/EMJVQh4 - вот новая крит. ошибка в логгере. Сразу же запустил траблшутер на питание, показывает, что все нормально.

Comment: я про описание самих событий... последнее кстати приложите подробнее тоже в вопрос.

Comment: чем дальше тем интереснее... и там уже уровень ошибки другой, как и причины

Comment: А, если про описание то да, сама винда не понимает почему она выключаеться) Ей что-то дает комманду это делать, но хрен пойми откуда.
И не совсем понял что приложить

Comment: все события `05:59:39`-`05:59:40`, если можно - то также в pastebin

Comment: https://pastebin.com/n7KDC1rF вот за промежуток 05:59:39-05:59:40 логи. Снизу вверх

Comment: у меня все мысли опять к железкам сводятся...но на этот раз уже к питанию ноута...

Comment: Угу, тоже начинаю думать, что что-то с системой питания... Но не могу понять почему оно рандомно выключаеться, ладно под нагрузкой, но тут совсем рандомно.  Я тут по совету другого человека скачал все драйвера с офф сайта леново для моего ноутбука, и по очереди их устанавливал. На каком то из драйверов выдало синий экран с critical process died. https://pastebin.com/BcAxLfvf вот лог, есть еще дамп, но он 1.5гб весит, если надо посмотреть, могу на ФО закинуть

Comment: относительно дров....вы можете проверить. Сделайте себе загрузочную флешку LiveUSB с какой-нибудь десктопной Linux'ой (например Ubuntu). Поработаейте на ней денек - другой...если будет продолжаться - значит версию с дровами можно опускать, а версию с железяками - начать проверять и отнести ноут на диагностику....

Comment: А для линкус не надо драйвера? Я просто никогда им не пользовался)

Comment: просто если у вас с железом проблемы, то такие вот постоянные сбой по цепочки могут поубивать остальные компоненты и чем дольше это продолжается - тем больше будет ущерб. Поэтому желательно поскорее проверить дрова/железки и если что - бежать и отдавать в диагностику в хороший сервисный центр

Comment: Там для большинства устройств есть открытые драйвера. Ну и проприетарные тоже в наличии. Lenovo  в целом дружит с Linux'ой

Comment: но как правило для более или менее комфортной работы - у вас все должно и так завестись

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview

Comment: Я понял. Вот новая ошибка, сегодня что-то совсем их много... https://imgur.com/a/Yj85gQ9
На этот раз не просто выключился, а синий экран с IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL.

Спасибо большое, теперь буду знать что скорее всего дело в железе, возможно просто какой-то брак с завода.

Comment: если у других владельцев этих ноутов тоже какие-то проблемы - то очень даже может быть что проблема в железке. Может серия компонентов каких-то проблемных была. В хороших сервисах, кстати, как правило знают о всех более или менее заметных и известных болячках конкретных серий ноутов и что у кого чаще всего выходит из строя и почему.